# How to avoid these kind of characters Ã¢â€žÂ¢ store into mysql table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Please any one help me how to avoid these kind of characters Ã¢â€žÂ¢  store into mysql table in php.

Thanks

Comment: Don't try to avoid it, try to handle them correctly

Comment: try to change charset

Comment: @MarkBaker,+1 in comment great sir, i appreciate you

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these characters you should run on the active MySQL connection the query `SET NAMES utf8` and also change the Charsets of the column to one that handles the characters correctly.

More Info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html.

Also be aware that that the text might be correctly stored and the problem might appear when you are displaying the page. If so you should add the charset meta tag as described here http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_meta_charset.asp

Comment: `SET NAMES` has the **security downside** of not effecting `real_escape_string` methods and should therefore not be used, see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) [*(additional information on my blogpost about UTF-8 in PHP/MySQL)*](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/mastering-unicodeutf-8-encoding-php/)